# Rails: Get count of values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column in my database called "experience" the user can save values called 0-2 years, 2-5 years, 5-10 years, 10+ years.  My question is how do I get a count of those values?  I'm not looking for a sum total of all, I'm trying to get a count of how many "2-5 years" values exist in the column and present that to the user in the view.

So in the view the user will see the values from the database tables column called experience and then how many jobs are posted and contain that value like this.

**Experience:**

0-2 years (3)

2-5 years (15)

Currently I am doing this in the view

```
<%= link_to "0-2 years", filtered_jobs_path(experience: '0-2 years', num_days_past: params[:num_days_past], search: params[:search]) %>
   (<%= Job.where(experience: '0-2 years').size %>)<br />
```

I was reading it's better to use size than count because size won't make another call to the database if it's already been loaded.  I'm not sure if I'm doing this in the most efficient way though, possibly I should be using a counter cache column?

Here are the calls that get made how I currently have it setup, seems like the database is constantly being queried even though I'm using .size

```
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."experience" = ?  [["experience", "0-2 years"]]

   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."experience" = ?  [["experience", "2-5 years"]]

   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."experience" = ?  [["experience", "5-10 years"]]

   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."experience" = ?  [["experience", "10+ years"]]

  Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 5], ["OFFSET", 0]]

   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group by experience and then count it:

```
Job.group(:experience).count
```

That would return a hash:

```
{
  '0-2 years' => 1,
  '10+ years' => 2,
  '2-5 years' => 1,
  '5-10 years' => 2
}
```

So in your view you could write something like this:

```
# in controller

@exp_names = ['0-2 years', '2-5 years', '5-10 years', '10+ years']
@exp_counts = Job.group(:experience).count

# in view

<% @exp_names.each do |name| %>
  <%= link_to name, filtered_jobs_path(experience: name, num_days_past: params[:num_days_past], search: params[:search]) %>
  (<%= @exp_counts[name] %>)
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the only thing is that the links aren't ordered the way I want on the page anymore.  Do you know how I could get the links returned so it would be in the order 0-2 years, 2-5 years, 5-10 years, 10+ years?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, getting "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"   coming from     <% @exp_names.each do |name| %>

Comment: Good to go now, I just had to add '@exp_names ' and '@exp_counts' inside the index action.  Thanks for all the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
Job.group(:experience).count
```

should give you an hash with as keys the experience field and as values the number of rows for that field

```
<% Job.group(:experience).count.each do |name, count| %>
  <%= link_to name, filtered_jobs_path(experience: name, num_days_past: params[:num_days_past], search: params[:search]) %>
  (<%= count %>)
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like this a lot! Great answer.

Comment: So I see Job.group(:experience).count returns 
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "jobs"."experience" AS jobs_experience FROM "jobs" GROUP BY "jobs"."experience"
 => {"0-2 years"=>1, "10+ years"=>2, "2-5 years"=>1, "5-10 years"=>2}  how do I call this in the view though?

Comment: I udpated my answer